# Бот сообщений сообщества не видит беседы

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Решил я написать бота для сообщений в сообществе во ВКонтакте с помощью **Python**'а и хотел чтобы он работал в беседах, да вот незадача, все мои попытки были тщетны.
Сначала я пытался *использовать VK API*, но как показала практика, *бот работал только в личных сообщениях сообщества*, я пошёл дальше и попробовал *метод прослушивания событий LongPoll*, вот пример кода:

```
import vk
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import random

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="токен сообщества с полностью выданными правами")
vk._auth_token()

session_api = vk.get_api()
lp = VkLongPoll(vk)

while True:
    for event in lp.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.text:
            if event.text == '1' or event.text == '2': #Если написать 1 или 2
                if event.from_user:                    #то бот ответит
                    vk.method("messages.send", {
                        "user_id":event.user_id,
                        "message":'ПРОГРАММИРОВАНИЕ ЗЛО',
                        "random_id": random.randomint(1, 2147123123)}
                    )
                elif event.from_chat:
                    vk.method("messages.send", {
                        "chat_id":event.chat_id,
                        "message":'ПРОГРАММИРОВАНИЕ ЗЛО',
                        "random_id": random.randomint(1, 2147123123)}
                    )
```

К сожалению данный код в теории должен работать и в беседах, однако беседы он не видит, хотя боту выдана привилегия *Администратора*.
И последняя моя попытка была это подключение к LongPoll-серверу и прослушивание каждого события по флагам, однако и тут мне сервер не помог, он тоже не видит беседы. Инструкцию по подключению к LongPoll-серверу брал на хабре [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/335106/), но пришлось немного переписывать для того чтобы он работал. (в итоге сервер плохо сохранил файл с кодом и я потерял его).
Запускал код Python я на pythonanywhere.com
Если кто знает решение, пожалуйста подскажите, так как в поддержку ВКонтакте я написать не могу по непонятным тому причинам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте данный код, прямо сейчас у меня так запущен бот:

```py
from random import random
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


vk_session = VkApi(token="[Ваш токен]")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "[id сообщества]")
vk = vk_session.get_api()

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:
        random_id = round(random() * 10 ** 9)
        chat_id = int(event.chat_id)
        message = "[Ваш ответ]"

        vk.messages.send(
            random_id=random_id,
            chat_id=chat_id,
            message=message,
        )
```

Comment: А то что VkBotLongPoll не может получить доступ (использовал твой код) не нормально?  
UPD: ошибка 15 acces denied  
UPD 2: вместо VkApi(token = ,,,) , пришлось использовать vk_api.VkApi(token = ,,,)

Comment: Так у Вас получилось?

P. S:
Только что запустил этот код, вставив свой токен и id сообщества.
Добавил бота в беседу и выдал ему права на чтение всей переписки.
Написал сообщение, он мне ответил.

Comment: Невероятно, но заработало, однако я так и не понимаю что же я не так делал, большое спасибо!!!

Comment: Это из-за `VkLongPoll`. В [документации](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/longpoll.html) указано, что это модуль для пользователей. Так как Вы авторизуетесь с ключом сообщества, Вам требуется `VkBotLongPoll`. Обратите внимание, что он в другом модуле, а именно в `vk_api.bot_longpoll.VkBotLongPoll`

Comment: Да, заметил, я вчера ещё собирался им воспользоваться, но думал что где-то просто косячу